# Switch XIB Views - Cocoa Mac

Tags: cocoa, macos, sdk, xib

I am pretty new to coding and would like to know how to switch XIB views on a button click. IS there also anyway to add animation when switching?

Thanks,

Kevin

Comment: im not working with the iphone api system. im creating a mac application.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

this is totally possible, but there are a few things you'll need to do. I imagine you are already familiar with connecting outlets to objects in your XIB, so the first thing you need to do is create the custom views in your XIB and connect them to outlets in your appDelegate. I suggest that one of the views be dragged into the window and one one be outside the window. That way, when the window loads, it already has one of your custom views as a subview. This just makes it easier to get started.

Then you're going to write an IBAction in the appDelegate and connect it to your button. Assuming that one of the custom views is already being hosted by the window, the IBAction should send a replaceSubviewWith message to the window's contentView animator like this `[[window.contentView animator] replaceSubview:firstView with:secondView];` where firstView and secondView are the pointer/outlets that you declared and connected to the views in your XIB.

This is sending the animator proxy of the window's content view a message which tells it to replace the old subview with the new one. The reason for sending the message to the view's animator proxy (and not the view itself) is that the transition will be carried out with the deafult CATransitionAnimation. Because you want it to be animated, right?

The reason why you shouldn't remove one subview and then add another is because animating the removal of a subview is actually quite tricky and requires the implementation of the delegate method animationDidEnd. This is because executing an animation on a view that has been removed from the view heirarchy does not make sense. I don't know why Apple hasn't changed this, but for now it will be one of the enduring quirks of CoreAnimation.

Let me know if that helps. I am happy to clarify! And welcome to Cocoa!

Comment: Just one question, can these "view" specifically the firstView and the secondView be located on different XIBs?

Comment: Yes, but they don't need to be. Is there any reason why you need them in separate xibs?

Answer (score 3):

An easy way to do this is to use a tabless NSTabView- you can lay everything out in IB so the pain is minimal.